# Ambiguous column name error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I know many people have posted about this but none of them seem to have the error the same way I do.

I get ERROR 1052 when ever I run this statement.

```
mysql> SELECT module_staff.StaffName AS Staff, 
              SUM(modules.HoursPerWeek) AS Total_Worked 
       FROM module_staff, modules 
       WHERE ModuleCode IN (SELECT ModuleCode
                            FROM module_staff 
                            WHERE StaffName ='Nigel Cosworth');
```

But This code below does work.

```
mysql> SELECT Title, 
              SUM(modules.HoursPerWeek) AS Total_Worked 
       FROM modules 
       WHERE ModuleCode IN(SELECT ModuleCode 
                           FROM module_staff
                           WHERE StaffName ='Nigel Cosworth');
```

module_staff has the columns ModuleCode and StaffName

and modules only column needed is HoursPerWeek, Title and ModuleCode

Comment: The problem is that you are referencing `ModuleCode` in the WHERE clause and it exists in both tables in the JOIN.  Which table do you want here?  You'll need to prefix the column with the table.

Comment: Ok thank you for the edit to my code also, I will bare this in mind next time posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error lies in the `JOIN`.
Try updating your query like this:

```
SELECT ms.StaffName AS Staff, SUM(m.HoursPerWeek) AS Total_Worked 
FROM module_staff ms
LEFT JOIN modules m
ON ms.ModuleCode = m.ModuleCode
WHERE ms.StaffName ='Nigel Cosworth';
```

Comment: You were right, Thank you for that. Also thank you for showing me the naming of tables within a statement to save on typing i'm still in the early days here

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT ms.StaffName AS Staff, SUM(m.HoursPerWeek) AS Total_Worked 
FROM module_staff ms
LEFT JOIN modules m
ON ms.ModuleCode = m.ModuleCode
WHERE ms.StaffName ='Nigel Cosworth';
```

will work for u....